Issues with Billing Address and Company Name Not Displaying on Quaderno Invoice
I am using the Quaderno PHP Composer package to create invoices in my application. I am correctly sending the billing address and company name while creating the invoice, but they are not showing up on the generated invoice. Below is the relevant code snippet:

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

class QuadernoService
{
    private $apiKey;
    private $apiUrl;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->apiKey = QUADERNO_KEY;
        $this->apiUrl = QUADERNO_URL;
        QuadernoBase::init($this->apiKey, $this->apiUrl);
    }

    public function createInvoice($transactionDetails, $items = [])
    {
        $transaction = new QuadernoTransaction($transactionDetails);
        $transaction->items = $items; // Assign items to the transaction
        $transaction_data = $transaction->save();
        $response = [
            "invoice_number" => null,
            "invoice_url" => null
        ];

        if ($transaction_data) {
            $response = [
                "invoice_url" => str_replace('http://', 'https://', $transaction->pdf),
                "invoice_number" => $transaction->number
            ];
        }
        return $response;
    }

    public function handleInvoiceCreation($transaction_data)
    {
        global $core;

        $Customer = $core->get_row('customers', '*', "WHERE CID = " . $transaction_data['customer_id']);

        $items = [
            [
                'description' => 'Linkingpress credits for guest posts and/or press releases',
                'quantity' => 1,
                'amount' => floatval($transaction_data['amount'])
            ]
        ];

        $transactionDetails = [
            'type' => 'sale',
            'payment' => [
                'method' => 'credit_card',
                'processor' => $transaction_data['payment_method'],
                'processor_id' => $transaction_data['transaction_id']
            ],
            'currency' => 'USD',
            'notes' => 'Description or notes here',
            'company_name' => 'Your Business Name' // Company name
        ];

        if ($Customer) {
            $transactionDetails['customer'] = [
                'first_name' => $Customer->firstname,
                'last_name' => $Customer->lastname,
                'email' => $Customer->email,
                'billing_address' => [
                    'address1' => 'Street Name',
                    'city' => 'City Name',
                    'postal_code' => 'Postal Code',
                    'country' => 'Country Code'
                ]
            ];
        }

        // Create the invoice
        $response = $this->createInvoice($transactionDetails, $items);
        $transaction_data['invoice_url'] = $response['invoice_url'];
        $transaction_data['invoice_number'] = $response['invoice_number'];

        return $transaction_data;
    }
}



I sent the billing address index and also tried by sending billing address inside customer. But it not works.

i solved it by myself as
 if ($Customer) {
            $transactionDetails['customer'] = [
                'first_name' => $Customer->firstname,
                'last_name' => $Customer->lastname,
                'email' => $Customer->email,
                'street_line_1' => 'Street Name',
                'city' => 'City Name',
                'postal_code' => 'Postal Code',
                'country' => 'Country Code'
                
            ];
        }

Billing details should be within in customer main index, not on billing address index
